# How do I hide the page title in Big Cartel?

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

Heres what im talking about: http://www.betrayalmiami.com/newsletter

The "newsletter" title is there because thats the name of the page, and i'd like for that to be gone. How can i basically hide the page title? I'm not sure whether it would be through html or css, editing the site layout, or whatever. The theme im using is nova. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` tag in each page gets assigned an ID based on the page's permalink, so in this case you can just add a line to your custom CSS to hide the `h1` element on the page, like so:

`#newsletter h1 { display: none }`